# End to end tests in PyTest

Tags: pytest, end-to-end

I use PyTest to write my unit-tests and I absolutely love it. Recently - a need for end-to-end/acceptance tests has shown up, and since I had bad experience with acceptance tests framework, I decided to do some researching if it's possible to write end to end tests in PyTest.

I won't get into too much details about the system in test, but what the applications do is to receive 3 messages from a customer (in JSON format), sprinkle some business layer magic on top of it, and then output 7 messages back to the customer. Here's couple of questions about structure and test design:

1. The `setup` part should create the 3 JSON messages, and send those to the system in test. I'm not sure `fixtures` is the proper way to handle it, but fixtures for me is a way to return an object with a state. So I would assume my `setup` is the same thing just on a bigger scope. So let's said I have a fixture named `setup` (module scope) that does those multiple actions needed for the test to work (creating the 3 JSON message and dispatching them). My instinct tells me I shouldn't have more than one `setup` fixture per test file/test class, however, I'm not sure how many tests I should have. I can make it more 'unit' like, and have 7 tests. Each will consume one message, and verify the message data is correct. Or - since 3 messages output 7 messages, and there is a direct connection between the setup and the results, I should use a single test that verify all 7 message in it. This will make my test method more complex because asserting separate values from the returned JSON is probably a bad idea - if the first message will fail, I will not be able to know if the 6 remaining message are OK or not (It's of-course easier to know what went wrong when you see the whole picture). So for a single test to work properly I will have to write a method that compare all 7 messages with expected results, and then raise a single assert with information about which of the 7 messages failed and why. So while verifying 7 messages feels right in testing context, It's more complex and does not follow the 'test a single thing and be simple`.
2. The `setup` create an entity called `random_test_entity` (along many other entities). The test need that information for asserting. So the setup fixture can either return a dict with all those values I will need later on in my test, OR - I can create another fixture which return a dict with values that both the setup fixture and the test will consume. Problem here is that I need to share data and state between my fixtures and test. And because I have no smart way of doing it, my fixture return data that is not strictly connected to the setup which feels strange. A fixture returning a list of values feel strange for me, but also splitting the setup fixture into multiple fixtures just so I can share data.
3. I'm using Ptest git repository as my bible on how to write unit-tests. I learned a lot about test design from it. Is there any source I can use to learn how to properly write end to end tests?

Thanks everyone!